# Error al subir un archivo en PHP

Tags: php, vps

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a un VPS de Aruba con CentOS usando php.

El código php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';
    use baseDeDatos\conexion as conexion;

    $target_file = "pdf/englishtest"."_".date("F")."_".rand(0,1000).substr(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]),-4);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if($imageFileType == "pdf") {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $mysqli = conexion\abrirConexion();
                $sql = "UPDATE datosapp SET Test='".$target_file."'";
                $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                header("Location: administrador.php");
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Sólo se admiten archivos PDF.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Este es el archivo php.ini

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

y cuando ejecuto el form para subir PDF's de menos de medio MegaByte, lo que se imprime es:
"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.".

Al hacer Print_r sobre $_FILES obtengo lo siguiente:

```
 Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => cv.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpeudTNd [error] => 0 [size] => 154193 ) )
```

Comment: $target_file apunta a la carpeta pdf. ¿Existe? ¿Tiene los permisos adecuados? ¿Te das cuenta que es una ruta relativa? por ahí pueden andar los fallos.

Comment: Hola! Tenías razón, eran los permisos de la carpeta. GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado gracias a @Neoniet
Eran los permisos de la carpeta. chmod 777 y solucionado.